# Change the URL id depend on the DropDownList selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a DropDownList which has a Car models

`@Html.DropDownList("Cars", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Cars, "Select a Value", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })`

i need the user must select a value also if he select a specific value send the id of the value to url to the action as a parameter

`<a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Registration", new { id = selected value of the dropdownlist item })" class="text-white"> Modify Registration</a>
<a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Registration", new { id = selected value of the dropdownlist item })" class="text-white"> Cancel Registration</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use javascript to achieve this. So for example you could give your anchor an unique id:

```
<a id="editRegistration" href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Registration", new { id = "initial value from the database" })" class="text-white">Modify Registration</a>
```

and then subscribe to the change event of the dropdown and update the href of the anchor:

```
<script>
    $('#Cars').change(function() {
        var url = "@Url.Action("Edit", "Registration", new { id = "#ID#" })";
        // replace the #ID# placeholder with the selected value
        var newHref = url.replace('#ID#', this.value);
        $('#editRegistration').attr('href', newHref);

        // do the same with the other anchor
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Darin i don't know the user will select which value from the dropdownlist to evaluate the `#ID#`

Comment: You don't need to evaluate anything. It's just a placeholder that you should hard-code as shown in my answer. The idea is that you subscribe to the `onchange` event of the dropdown using javascript and inside this callback you simply replace the placeholder with the actual selected value and replace the `href` attribute of your anchor with the new url.

Comment: i didn't understand this words : // replace the #ID# placeholder with the selected value. that mean what ?

Comment: which selected value ?

Comment: `this.value`, as shown in my answer. Inside the `onchange` callback `this.value` will contain the selected value of the dropdown. So you just plug it into the url: `var newHref = url.replace('#ID#', this.value);`.

Comment: The id still with the default value which i had initialized it with

Comment: Can you check if the `change` event is raised? Maybe your dropdown has a different `id` on the client and you might need to adjust the `$('#Cars')` selector. Also make sure that you have placed this code inside a `$(document).ready` handler or at the end of the markup, before closing the body to ensure that the dropdown is present in the DOM before subscribing to its change event. Also you should make sure that jQuery is included in your references as this example depends on it.

Comment: Sorry For Disturb but can you help me to know how know if the change event is raised ?

Comment: Put an `alert` inside it.

Comment: After using alert it doesn't raised

Comment: OK, so you need to verify that the id of your dropdown is indeed `Cars` and if it isn't adjust the selector accordingly. Also check the console for potential errors.

Comment: after put the script inside the `$(document).ready it's raised correctly but still not working correctly

Comment: the id which going to the Edit action doesn't changed

Comment: I need to notify you that the id will used in another controller

Comment: it's working but the url now : http://localhost/AUC.CarRegistration/@Url.Action(%22Edit%22,%20%22Registration%22,%20new%20%7B%20id%20=%20%229%22%20%7D)

Comment: if i write this will get error :`var url = "@Url.Action("Edit", "Registration", new { id = "#ID#" })";`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135606/discussion-between-ahmed-hossam-alhansy-and-darin-dimitrov).

Comment: If i use this 

`var editUrl = 'Registration/Edit?id=' + id + '';
 $('#editRegistration').attr('href', editUrl);`
it's working correctly